# ListAnimate — restore frames to original position after interaction during a pause

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I have a `ListAnimate` where the frames consist of graphics made of lines and points. I want to make sure that, when the animation is paused and then resumed, all frames appear normal again, so if you stop it to rotate the plot (it's 3D), after a loop it looks normal again.

My code is the following:

```
ListAnimate[
  {Labeled[Show[Graphics3D[g0, ViewPoint -> Front], ImageSize -> Full], S0, Top], 
   Labeled[Show[Graphics3D[g1, ViewPoint -> Front], ImageSize -> Full], S1, Top], 
   ...,
   Labeled[Show[Graphics3D[g51, ViewPoint -> Front], ImageSize -> Full], S51, Top]}, 
  4, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

where g1, ..., g51 are the images and S1, ..., S51 are timestamps that I print on the top.

I read in another answer that setting `PreserveImageOptions -> False` should take care of this. However, the option doesn't do anything, I tried all possible placing of it as well as wrapping the whole thing in a `Manipulate` expression.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the graphics in `Show`?

Comment: In order to add `ImageSize-> Full`.
I'm a newbie in Mathematica... It didn't work inside `Graphics3D`

Comment: `ImageSize->` is an option of `ListAnimate[]`, you can remove the `Show[]`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
g = {g0, g1, g2, g3, g4};
s = {S0, S1, S2, S3, S4};
Animate[Labeled[Graphics3D[g[[i]], ViewPoint -> Front], s[[i]],Top],
{i, 1, 5, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False,PreserveImageOptions -> False]
```

Comment: It works! May I ask you how should I manage the frames per second rate?

Comment: Answering my own question: `DefaultDuration -> fps_rate * (max_index+1)`

Comment: Also, I think you meant `{i, 0, 4, 1}` (sorry for multiple comments)

Comment: @Reiza `{i, 1, 5, 1}` actually,  I'll amend the answer. Glad it works, unlike `Python`, `Mathematica` indices start at `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is a default feature. For example

```
ListAnimate[Table[Graphics3D[{Hue[x], Cuboid[]}], {x, 0, 1, .01}]]
```

If you pause it, rotate the `Cuboid` and then play again, you will see that it will resume its initial position.

Comment: @Reiza And if not, please post your complete code so others can test it.

Comment: I guess I should add the `Table[]`? It does not work like that for me: once you rotate a frame, it stays there in the next loop.
@Feyre It's unfortunately a massive file with several thousands lines; however, each of the g's is a list of lines, e.g., `Line[{{10805, 1520, 4408}, {10805, 1520, 0}}], Line[{{10905, 1520, 
   4386}, {10905, 1520, 0}}], Line[{{11005, 1520, 4364}, {11005, 1520,
    0}}], Line[{{805, 1320, 9758}, {805, 1320, 0}}], Line[{{1205, 
   1320, 9753}, ....`

Comment: @Reiza A representative sample then.

Comment: @Feyre Thanks for speedy reply. I manually created a minimal example: pastebin.com/embed_iframe/P6VC0Zqa

Comment: @Feyre and btw `ImageSize-> Full` doesn't work in there..

Comment: Which version you are using. It works fine M10.

Comment: @Sumit the latest (10.4.1.0), downloaded just yesterday.

Comment: @Sumit What I am getting is, when the viewpoint is changed for a certain time frame, when the animation is played back, it jumps to that viewpoint every time it reaches that time frame again. I have Linux, might be a platform dependent thing.

Comment: I also think that @Feyre. Someone might check it with different os or version. Till then lets have a cup of coffee :)

Comment: @Feyre The same problem appears in Windows.